# Drupal view to display node activity

Tags: views, nodes

I need to provide a view which gives a simple list of user activity with regards to node 'events' - e.g. any updates to fields, new nodes created, nodes deleted etc..

For example,

> ```
> Last Updated:         Activity
> -----------           --------   
> ..   
> 5 mins ago -          username has updated Title for node:nid
> 6 mins ago -          username has updated Price for node:nid
> 7 mins ago -          node:nid has been deleted
> 13 mins ago -         new node:nid has been created..
> ..etc
> ```

Has anyone achieved something similar? If so - how did you go about this? Did you use a module?

Comment: You can checkout from [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279696), that which one is more suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement it seems [Activity](https://www.drupal.org/project/activity) module will suite you. But again this module is in Dev version for Drupal 7. So if you are ready to use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module then go ahead. Since you are only tracking the node create & edits then in Rules module you will get all the conditions and events.

But if you are also okay with developing custom module then I'd suggest to write a custom module and with all the HOOKs provided for nodes you can create the desired records and store those in a table. See the HOOKs for nodes [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7).

Let me know if I can assist you with creating a custom module.